# How do I get prompted for a hostname in a preseed?

Tags: installation, preseed

I want my automated install to ask me for a hostname.

This is my [preseed file](http://paste.ubuntu.com/877277/) and this is my pxe startup conf

```
LABEL auto64-1110
        MENU LABEL ^C Ubuntu 11.10 64-bit auto install met proxy
        KERNEL ubuntu-installer-1110/amd64/linux
        APPEND vga=normal initrd=ubuntu-installer-1110/amd64/initrd.gz ramdisk_size=16417 root=/dev/ram rw preseed/url=http://pxe-int.hobby.nl/auto-install-ubuntu-hobbynet.txt locale=en_US setup/layoutcode=en_US console-setup/layoutcode=en interface=eth1 netcfg/dhcp_timeout=60 netcfg/get_hostname=install keyboard-configuration/layoutcode=us --
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the answer myself.

I removed `netcfg/get_hostname=install` from the pxe boot line